# AFNetworking - How to specify multiple values for one key

Tags: afnetworking

I am trying to pass multiple values for one parameter key to an HTTP request using the AFHTTPClient method "postPath". However, the parameters variable is an NSDictionary so I can not set multiple values for my key "email". I've tried sending the e-mail values as a comma separated string but that does not work as my server returns an error saying I have not specified any e-mail value.

I did read in the documentation about using multipartFormRequestWithMethod method but I could not completely figure out how to make this work. Can anyone provide an example of using this method with multiple values for a single key?

Thanks

Rich

Comment: Since NSDictionary doesn't allow duplicate keys, this prevents you from fulfilling your particular use-case.
What you could do is taking the NSMutableURLRequest created in this method, and manually construct the POST body string yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Combining the multi query values for one key.

If you use NSDictionary + NSSet you get query url without [] from NSArray.

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSSet setWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil], @"myKey", nil];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/path" parameters:params];
```

PS: Better late than never...

Comment: What if I want to send multiple parameters with same value also? This
`[NSSet setWithObjects:@"value1", @"value1", @"value2", @"value2", nil]`
are not working.

Answer (score 4):

Combining the multi values for the one key.

using NSDictionary + NSArray

For example:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"param1", @"value2", @"param2", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value3",@"value4",@"value5",nil], @"param3", nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/yourhostpath" parameters:params];
```

you need to replace "url" and "yourhostpath" to your own, please reference AFHttpClient demo code of AFNetworking for this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define multiple values for a single key. However, you can define a key to have an array, which itself contains multiple values.

That said, it doesn't seem like `email` would be a field that should have multiple definitions. If you do want to accept multiple values, you should probably rename that parameter to `emails`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try passing a the email parameter an NSArray but the server similarly responded that I had not passed an e-mail address. Any ideas?

Comment: So it appears the AFNetworking code is taking the key of "email" and turning it into "email[]" which is why the server does not recognize a passed e-mail address. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @RichMorey That's sort of the point: `email[]` is a convention used by many frameworks like Rails to denote that multiple values are being passed. Did you write the API? If you're getting a validation like that, it seems that the server just wants a single e-mail. Why not just do that?

Comment: I did not write the API. I am working with a client who created the API. They have previously received multiple e-mail addresses without the use of []. I created a hack to remove the [] from the key name before adding it to the request and this is working. I have spoken to our client about possibly changing the API to support the [] notation.