# how to send array as a parameter in Afnetwoking post method?

Tags: ios, ios6, afnetworking

hi i need to send a array as a one of the parameter in Afnetworking Query String

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://192.008.0.28/aaa/a/"]];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"20", @"Miles", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil], @"Interval", nil];

    [httpClient postPath:iUpdateNotificationMethod parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

But server side we got "Miles":20,"Intervals":null how to fix it 
Thanks,

Comment: Is this what your looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088025/afnetworking-how-to-specify-multiple-values-for-one-key

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:OAuthBaseURL];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (int i =0; i < [userIDs count]; i++) {
        NSString *userID = [[userIDs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSDictionary *tmpDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:userID , [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ids[%i]",i], nil];
        [parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:tmpDict];
    }
    [client postPath:@"/user"
          parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSData *data = (NSData *)responseObject;
                NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"jsonStr %@",jsonStr);

            }
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                [self showError];
            }
     ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're submitting an array, AFNetworking is generating a different parameter name and overloads it with the values you supply. For example, your request generates the following querystring:

```
Interval[]=1&Interval[]=2&Interval[]=3&Miles=20
```

This is defined in `AFHTTPClient.m` in the `AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue` function.

If you want to keep the original parameter, you should decide how to convert your `NSArray` to `NSString` by yourself. For example, you can do something like `[myArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]` and then split it back to elements on the server. If you choose this method, beware of using characters that might appear in your actual data.

Comment: I am seeing a similar array encoding. Can you explain how to fix this more clearly? Thx

Comment: This is a design issue. If you pass an array as an HTTP parameter, AFNetworking will need to convert it to an HTTP query string. You can think of various ways to do that (such as concatenating the input with `,`). The chosen method was different - to mark the parameter as an array by prefixing it with `[]`. Therefore, you'll either need to change your server side to handle this or pass an `NSString` which is crafted from your joined original array in the client.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will work: 
    params = @{ @"Miles": @"20", @"Interval": @[@"1",@"2",@"3"] };

Comment: This will produce the exact `NSDictionary` as it was created before.

Comment: Sorry - You are correct.  I was thinking he was using AFJSONRequestOperation.  But in that case either would have worked as well.